# How to reject token with invalid claims

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth, openid, identityserver4

I have an application ASP.net 4.X it uses  `UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` for authentication to an Identity server 4 application.

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = identityServerUrl,
                ClientId = clientId,
                Scope = "openid profile testapi",
                ClientSecret = secret,
                RedirectUri = basePath + "/signin-oidc",
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = basePath,
                ResponseType = "id_token token code",
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
                UseTokenLifetime = false,

                ....................
```

All of this works fine currently.   However I have an issue.  If something happens in the Identity server and it does not return all of the claims in the token that i need.   I need a way to refuse it without ending in some kind of endless loop of login which i currently have.

I was wondering if there is some place in the middlewear that i can add something like

```
 var needed= claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "NeedThisClaim")?.Value;
```

If its not there then kick it out and refuse the user access.  I was thinking of putting it in `SecurityTokenValidated` but I am not sure that's the best place or not. I am also not sure how to reject the token gracefully.

How do you verify that a token contains the required claims when authenticating an application.